# how to do Post paid billing for monthly plans using Stripe (php)

Tags: php, stripe-payments, subscription

How can I create a post paid billing for the subscription of monthly plan using Stripe(php) and if plan is paused for some days then would stripe cater it or not and if not then how to cater it for number of hours the subscription remained active.

PS: I searched a lot but could not find any thing good for post paid billing in Stripe.

Comment: Does Stripe not provide documentation on how to use their product?

Comment: Stripe provides everything except post-paid billing I have gone through every documentation

Comment: The only solution I have found is to used first month as trial period but it is not a standard solution

Answer (score 1):

To implement a kind of monthly post-billing system, you could use a monthly subscription whose `amount` is `0` and then use webhooks sent at the end of every every billing cycle to charge customers for what they have used during the last month, using **invoice items**.

It's important to understand how subscription billing cycles work, and how customers are billed for 2 different things, at the end of every billing cycle (every month if the subscription `interval` is `month`):

- First, the customer pays the amount of the subscription for the upcoming cycle, so it's kind of **pre-paid** system because the customer pays for the service he/she is going to use during the next month.
- In addition, the customer may be charged for one or several invoice items that were previously added to the upcoming invoice, so this is the **post-paid** part.

You could use webhooks, listening to the `invoice.created` event, to perform some business logic, checking the customer's activity, and add items to the invoice, if necessary.
If the customer did not use your service at all during the last month, you would not add any invoice item and the customer would not pay anything, since the subscription amount is `0`.

This is the gist, check this document for more details about subscriptions and invoices: https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/invoices

> When Stripe automatically generates an invoice for a recurring
>   payment, your site is notified via webhooks (an `invoice.created`
>   event). Stripe waits approximately an hour before attempting to pay
>   that invoice. In that time, you can add invoice items to the
>   recently-created invoice so that the forthcoming payment covers it.